# Unable to get data from json file in ember js

Tags: ember.js

I am new to ember js ,i want to get data from a json file i am not gettind any output in browser.

**app/route/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
   export default Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function(){
        return this.$.getJSON("app.json");
      }
});
```

**app/template/index.hbs**

```
<h1> I won  {{tot}}  today! </h1>
```

**app.json**

```
{ "tot": 100}
```

Is it have to use adapter concept to render data from json file?

Comment: which version of ember your using? if ur using ember-cli, keep the app.json file in public folder

Comment: Thank you for your response I got output but it haven't included the json file. The output is "I won today!" that's it.

Comment: I am using ember-cli.I have placed the json in public folder now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we used Ember 1.x, we used this kinda notation to access the model's values ie.

```
{{tot}}
```

instead of

```
{{model.tot}}
```

But now if have a model, then it should be accessed with

```
{{model.propertyName}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to access the data through the model i.e.

```
<h1> I won  {{model.tot}}  today! </h1>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the correct output.But can u explain why to use {{model.tot}} here.

Comment: Its the way ember works. The result of the model hook in your route will be placed in the controller property named "model". And in your template you are actually accessing controller properties.

Comment: ok thank you.Then is it possible to access the json file through index controller.